# Excel 2010 PowerPivot: How do I avoid apostrophes being displayed as â€™?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, encoding, powerpivot

When I import a text file to PowerPivot containing apostrophes, they are automatically converted to **â€™**.

I've been manually correcting the few that I find in the PowerPivot window, however when I do this in a column header it causes problems refreshing the data.

A quick Google tells me that [â€™ often appears in place of apostrophes when there is a text encoding mismatch](http://askleo.com/why_do_i_get_odd_characters_instead_of_quotes_in_my_documents/). It seems that I need to make sure PowerPivot is reading the data as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

How can I do this in PowerPivot? I've tried searching online with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the default encoding PowerPivot applies to incoming data is [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

This means you need to specify UTF-8 as the character encoding each time you import a new file, or you can edit an **Existing Connection** by clicking the **Edit** button from here:

[image]

Click the **Advanced** button from the **Table Import Wizard**. You can set the encoding here.

[image]